# How does a creature counter the Frightened condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, optional-rules, fear, intimidation

Some conditions have obvious counters—-for example, if prone, a creature can stand. But how does a creature counter being frightened of another who has successfully intimidated it into being frightened?

The condition is active “while the source of fear is within line of sight,” so it would seem that if an intimidator or the frightened creature moves behind another creature/solid object or if the intimidator hides, the frightened condition will become inactive for any frightened creature while it can no longer see the source of its fear. But could a Wisdom saving throw against the Charisma score of the intimidator on each subsequent turn make sense as a way to end the condition against the intimidator, at least until there is another intimidation attempt?

Comment: Welcome to the stack brethvoice, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I’m not sure I understand the question here. Are you asking about how the rules handle intimidation and the frightened condition? You tagged with house-rules and optional-rules, so I’m not sure if you’re looking for something else.

Comment: What's the source of the fear? Typically the source defines how long it lasts and what it takes to remove it. If you're homebrewing a new source of fear, that's for you to decide.